# Error while passing url as parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, firebug

I have a program in which calling a script function in dblclick of a tr.Also Passing some arguments which is generated dynamically

Part of my markup is

```
<tr id="#ID#_#VERSION_ID#" ondblclick="ShowAssetPreviewPopup(#PreviewPath#, #UUID#, #GENERAL_VIRTUAL_PATH#)"
```

The preview path will be replaced by something like this 'http://example.somethingsomething.mp4' and in the same way other 2 parameteres too. Up to here every thing is ok and as I click that tr the following function will get evoked

```
function ShowAssetPreviewPopup(PreviewPath, UUID, LowresVirtualpath) {   
            $("#divPreviewPopUp").find("#divVideoPreview").html("example");
            $("#divPreviewPopUp").css({"display:block"});
            $("#divPreviewPopUp").css({ "top": (($(window).height() / 2) - ($("#divPreviewPopUp").height() / 2)) });
            $("#divPreviewPopUp").css({ "left": (($(window).width() / 2) - ($("#divPreviewPopUp").width() / 2)) });
}
```

But an error is occurring in Firebug

[image]

What would be the reason and how to solve this?

Comment: Clearly that doesn't look like a string.

Comment: is there any way to do that from my markup

Comment: Also add the link of your fiddle ,so its easy to get error on your code! http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume #PreviewPath# is a string variable from your template engine. You have to surround these string variables by single quotes.

```
<tr id="#ID#_#VERSION_ID#" ondblclick="ShowAssetPreviewPopup('#PreviewPath#', #UUID#, '#GENERAL_VIRTUAL_PATH#')">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
$("#divPreviewPopUp").css("display:block");
```

to:

```
$("#divPreviewPopUp").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: another option : `$("#divPreviewPopUp").css({"display":"block"});`